# Change cursor with .mouseenter and .mouseleave function

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, cursor

I wrote this code to modify the cursor but I don't know how to continue to reach my final goal.
I would like the cursor triple his size, get 50% opacity and a text "view" appear over it when the mouse moves over a link. Thank you for the help.

```
<body onload = "followMouse();">
<div class="wrap">
<div id="ball"></div>
</div></body>
```

---

```
.wrap {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#ball {
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     background: #0034fc;
     border-radius: 50%;
     position: fixed;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
     pointer-events: none;
}

* {
cursor: none;
}
```

---

```
 var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
 var $on = document.addEventListener.bind(document);

 var xmouse, ymouse;
 $on('mousemove', function (e) {
      xmouse = e.clientX || e.pageX;
      ymouse = e.clientY || e.pageY;
 });

 var ball = $('#ball');
 var x = void 50,
      y = void 50,
      dx = void 50,
      dy = void 50,
      tx = 50,
      ty = 50,
      key = -1;

 var followMouse = function followMouse() {
      key = requestAnimationFrame(followMouse);

      if(!x || !y) {
           x = xmouse;
           y = ymouse;
      } else {
           dx = (xmouse - x) * 0.125;
           dy = (ymouse - y) * 0.125;
           if(Math.abs(dx) + Math.abs(dy) < 0.1) {
                x = xmouse;
                y = ymouse;
           } else {
                x += dx;
                y += dy;
           }
      }
      ball.style.left = x + 'px';
      ball.style.top = y + 'px';
 };
```

> i don't know how to complete the function
> jQuery( "a" ).mouseenter(function() {
> jQuery( "#ball" ).fadeTo( "slow" , 0, function() {
> // Animation complete.
> });
> });
> jQuery( "a" ).mouseleave(function() {
> jQuery( "#ball" ).fadeTo( "slow" , 1, function() {
> // Animation complete.

```
  });
});

 </script>
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle for the same

Comment: I don't know how to do. If i put all as code he said me "it looks like is complete" and i can''t edit